# How bad is it for a UIView to hold information on the Model (Business Object)

Tags: iphone, ios

This question is specific to iOS development.

Imagine you use `UITableView` and inside the `UITableViewCells` you show information regarding one or more of your application business objects through a bit more complex class that we'll call `ComplexBOView`.

Now you want to trigger a specific action when the user taps this view contained in your `UITableCellView` (the event can be triggered through a `UITapGestureRecognizer`)

Most of the time what is considered "best practice" is to use the `tag` property of the `UIView` to actually go back to your model and retrieve the correct business object.

This often is suitable but in some cases it can come very handy to hold a pointer to the business object used to built your `ComplexBOView`.

```
@interface ComplexBOView : UIView
{
    UILabel* lblSummary;
    // ....

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture;
    NSObject* businessObject_;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject* businessObject;
```

The idea behind this, is to actually directly go back to the businessObject when the user tapped the view.

Two questions here

- Is it really bad to have NSObject* information inside the UIView ?
- Should this information be retained meaning the relationship between the view and the model becomes here much stronger (ownership of the view towards the object) ?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general advice is

> Views don't own data!

and it's a good advice. It can save you a lot of trouble in the long run. But what does **own** mean? If you look at a `UIButton` or a `UILabel`, the button has a `title` the label a `text` property. So they are holding some data, they have to - the alternative would have to have a delegate that is asked for the text every time they get drawn.

So what does that mean in your case? Well that depends. If your `ComplexBOView` is just generic view that is specifically designed to **display** your specific business object, it wouldn't be the worst to hold that object in a property of it (just my opinion).

Of course you loose the possibility to easily reuse that view with a different model, but maybe that isn't an option anyway, because it's so specific. Of course you could move all that code from the `ComplexBOView` to the controller. But as you said then you also have to maintain a connection between each model object and the appropriate view. (Btw. I wouldn't use the `tag` to do that, it's better to just use an `NSDictionary instead)

On the other hand Trausi and Michael do have valid points. If you break that "rule" this one time, you might get loose and break it on every other occasion and before you know it, you end up with lots of custom views each holding a reference to some part of your model. In the long run you might make changes to your model (maybe in ways you never expected in the first place - and trust me, that **is** going to happen more often than not) and then you have to go to every single subclass and adjust them. Of course if that model-specific code lives in your controller you also have to modify all of that, but at least it's all in one place.

So to sum up, those best practices, advice and design patterns are there for a good reason. They proved themselves useful in countless cases. So in general you do good by just following them. There are however cases where it might be worth violating them, but you have to have some very good reasons and you should be aware of the consequences.

Ultimately, it's your code, your design, your decision. Maybe you guess wrong, but some lessons have to be learned the hard way. Next time you know what to do and, more important, **why**. Making your own experiences is always valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You should stick to the delegate design. You never know when you might need help with the code and people expect to use a delegate. This would spaghetti-fy your code in my opinion.

Remember that Views get recycled, especially in tableviews. Once the view is out of sight, it is re-used, so any logic you put in there would be complicated to maintain to say the least

Answer (score 1):

Trausti Thor is right. As soon as you begin that kind of short cut, it's the death of a thousand compromises (or to put it another way,  the technical debt just heaps up until it the resulting code base is so scary no one wants to touch it in case they break something else).

Whenever you have the chance to do it right, first time, do it, because there will be times when commercial, or other, pressures force you to do otherwise and these are unavoidable but you want to minimise the impact of such compromises by making them the exception.

Finally, if it's an exception, almost a blot on your code, you are probably going to be more inclined to go back and fix it during quieter times.